# How to Preserve Non-Whitespace Characters When Using `sed`

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I am using a `sed` expression to convert a straight quote to a curly quote.
I want to convert "Linux programmer's manual" to "Linux programmer’s manual".
I need it to detect if there is a non-whitespace character before and affter the straight quote.
And if there is, replace the straight quote with the curly quote.
I tried this:

```bash
sed "s/\S'\S/’/"
```

But that resulted in it also replacing the non-whitespace characters:

```
Linux programme’ manual
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture them:

```
sed -e :1 -e "s/\([^[:space:]]\)'\([^[:space:]]\)/\1’\2/g" -e t1
```

(here using the `[^[:space:]]` in place of that non-standard perl-like `\S`).

The `t1` is to cover inputs like `X'Y'Z`, where the `s/.../.../g` would not replace the `Y'Z` with `Y’Z` as the `Y` had already been part of an earlier replacement.

If using `perl` (where `\S` comes from), you could use look around operators:

```
perl -pe "s/(?<=\S)'(?=\S)/’/g"
```

Some `sed` implementations do support perl-like regexps like `ssed` with `-R` or ast-open's `sed` with `-P`, but not the most common `sed` implementations, not the GNU implementation which that `\S` suggests you're using.

Instead of hard-coding that U+2019 character in your current locale character encoding, you could do:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe "s/(?<=\S)'(?=\S)/\x{2019}/g"
```

Or:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe "s/(?<=\S)'(?=\S)/\N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}/g"
```

For the `'` to be replaced with `’` encoded as per the locale of the user invoking your script. For instance, `’` is encode as one 0xa2 byte in the ISO8859-7 Greek single byte charset, 0xe2 0x80 0x99 in UTF-8, 0xa1 0xa6 in BIG5 or BIG5-HKSCS.